# Battery charge percentage jumps from 100% straight to 93%

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery charge suddenly drops from about 25% to 6%](https://superuser.com/questions/155395/battery-charge-suddenly-drops-from-about-25-to-6)
>   [Laptop shuts down when battery meter is relatively full. When I plug in and reboot, battery meter correctly says 1% and charging](https://superuser.com/questions/434729/laptop-shuts-down-when-battery-meter-is-relatively-full-when-i-plug-in-and-rebo)

I have a new laptop battery that I charge to 100% and then discharge to 50% and charge again as Li-ion batteries should not be totally discharged.

However, today I noticed that after it showed 100% and I unplugged it, it jumped to 94% in a split second.
The moment I put it back in charge, it showed me a 100% again.

What could be causing this jumping?
Additionally, what I also observed was that I had left my laptop at 44% charge when I shut it down and when I restarted it, it was at 6%.

Laptop: HP Pavilion DV4-2126TX.
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty battery. If it's 'new' take it back.  If it's a no-name battery, consider contacting the notebook manufacturer for a validated replacement battery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Battery charge suddenly drops from about 25% to 6%](http://superuser.com/questions/155395/battery-charge-suddenly-drops-from-about-25-to-6), [Laptop shuts down when battery meter is relatively full. When I plug in and reboot, battery meter correctly says 1% and charging](http://superuser.com/questions/434729/laptop-shuts-down-when-battery-meter-is-relatively-full-when-i-plug-in-and-rebo?lq=1)